# Destructuring same name object/key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```
 const test = {
      test: []
    }

    if (test) { // if the object it's not empty I want to do something
      // I tried this but it won't work:
      let { test } = test
    }
```

Any way of destructure the key from the object. It's a pain to always do `test.test` every time I want to access it's value. I can't change the names of any of it, so that is out of the question.

Comment: Note: when something "doesn't work" it's helpful to include the actual error message. "It doesn't work" is not diagnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to check object if it is not empty like:

```
if (Object.keys(test).length){
```

And to deconstructure, you'll need to have different name as it cannot have same name:

```
let { test: testArr } = test
console.log(testArr)
```

As per the comment, commented by [El Aoutar Hamza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7513718/el-aoutar-hamza) under the post of Dave Newton

> But the assignment let { test } = test is done within a if statement, which means that test declared inside if should normally shadow the variable declared outside if, shouldn't it? why is it any different when using destructring?

I would like to state that it is not allowed to have same name coz, it will throw error. You cannot access the variable before its initialization.

When you define:

```
let { test } = test
```

It will behave like: (pseudo code to understand)

```
let test = undefined
{ test } = test 
// this cannot be accessed as it's value is not initialized.
```

Hope, you're clear what I meant.

Comment: IMO this answer should have gotten an upvote before mine: it's more-correct, and more detailed. (Although the object test has a different meaning than the original code.)

Comment: Agree :) @DaveNewton

Comment: Just as a side note, `let { test } = test` will only fail if `test` hasn't been declared before .. `let test = { test: 'test' }; let { test } = test;` will work ..

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza Ah, sorry. You cannot do that as well. Note to two let variables.